# Merge two sorted arrays in place in O(1) space

Tags: arrays, sorting, in-place

Can someone please help me understand the algorithm / code for this problem

given two integer arrays, sort them such that, initial numbers are placed in first array and remaining numbers in second array.
For example:

```
Input: ar1[ ] = {1, 5, 9, 10, 15, 20}

        ar2[] = {2, 3, 8, 13}

Output: ar1[ ] = {1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 9}

         ar2[] = {10, 13, 15, 20}
```

Code:

```
    void merge(int ar1[], int ar2[], int m, int n)
{
    // Iterate through all elements of ar2[] starting from
    // the last element
    for (int i=n-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        //Find the smallest element greater than ar2[i]. Move all
        //   elements one position ahead till the smallest greater
        //   element is not found
        int j, last = ar1[m-1];
        for (j=m-1; j >= 0 && ar1[j] > ar2[i]; j--)
            ar1[j+1] = ar1[j];

        // If there was a greater element
        if (j != m-1)
        {
            ar1[j+1] = ar2[i];
            ar2[i] = last;
        }
    }
}
```

I saw this solution on this website : http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-two-sorted-arrays-o1-extra-space/

Comment: Your reference seems to explain the algorithm well. If you can specify what you did not understand, it would help in guiding you better.

Comment: Hi, I am not understanding the comparison between the last element of ar2, and how it is getting placed in the correct place. What is the rational or invariant here?. Also won't it through arrayIndexOutOfBound exception at "ar1[j+1] = ar[j]" ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you *are* correct in assuming that there would be access violation in that loop. An outer if statement encompassing both the loop & the following if statement and checking if the rightmost element is greater than ar2[i] in ar1 would be sufficient to prevent that violation.

Comment: Hi @ilim thank you for the explanation. However, lets consider the first iteration:
where i = 3, j = 5
ar1[j] > ar2[i] i.e 20 > 13 is true,
and hence it will enter the for loop,
Now since j = 5, updating the ar1[j+1] will throw an exception.

Comment: @AjinkyaKale Oh, I forgot to add that you have to start the inner loop from m-2 once you add the if statement I mentioned in the comment above. As to the rest of my explanation regarding the code you provided, you may refer to my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Intuition

For each element `ar2[i]` of `ar2`(i.e. inside the outer loop) basically you find the index `j` in `ar1` such that all the elements of `ar1` in range `[(j+1), (m-1)]` are greater than `ar2[i]`. Then you take the smallest element in that range and *throw it off* of `ar1` to `ar2`, specifically to the cell with index `i`, where the value in `ar2[i]` once resided before being transferred to `ar1`.

The reason of this transfer of `ar2[i]` to `ar1[j+1]` is the effort to gather the smallest m elements in `ar1` and the rest in `ar2`. The arguably elegant thing this algorithm does is traversing `ar2` from right to left. If you recall that both `ar1` and `ar2` are sorted, what going from right to left on `ar2` helps achieve *using constant extra space* is as follows.

As you go from right to left on `ar2` you encounter decreasing, or at least non-increasing, values in `ar2[i]`. This means that you will find decreasing or non-increasing values of `ar1[m-1]` to replace them with. Basically the smallest elements `ar1[m-1]` greater than `ar2[i]` will be non-increasing as the value `ar2[i]` decreases as we go from right to left.

Consequently, the elements we throw off `ar1` to `arr2` in each iteration of outer loop will also be in non-increasing or decreasing order, and we will place them to indices in decreasing order, keeping `ar2` ordered.

#### Invariant Approach

A possible though rather informal **invariant** would be that `ar1` and `ar2` would be sorted after each iteration, with at most a single element of `ar2`, say `ar2[i]`, for which there exist at least 1 `ar1[k]>ar2[i]` is swapped with an element in `ar1` in a manner not violating the sorted order of either array.

Initially the elements are ordered. After each iteration, if there exists an element smaller than `ar2[i]` in `ar1` at index `j`, all range greater than `ar2[i]` is shifted to right by 1. `ar2[i]` is placed to `ar1[j+1]` so that it does not violate the order of `ar1`. Then, the **previously last** element of `ar1`, which does not fit in `ar1` anymore, is put ito `ar2[i]`.

It is straightforward to see that order of `ar1` is maintained at each iteration of the outer loop. Order of `ar2` requires a bit more of focus.

Every time we put an element of `ar2` to `ar1`, we know that the previously last element of `ar1` we will put to `ar2` (i.e. in place of `ar2[i]`) is known to be greater than `ar2[i]`, as it is greater than or equal to `ar1[j+1]` which was greater than `ar2[i]`. (`ar2[i] < ar1[j+1] <= last`)

Also, any previously replaced elements in `ar2`(i.e. the ones to the right of the ith index of `ar2`) have been replaced with values *last* that were greater than or equal to the value last in current iteration, as `ar1` was initially ordered.

Therefore after each iteration, `ar2` remains ordered as well, and after the algorithm terminates, there exists no element `ar2[i]` such that there is an element `ar1[k] > ar2[i]`.

Comment: Hi, @ilim thank you very much, this is spot on explanation. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MergeArray {

    public static void mergeArray(int[] input1, int[] input2) {

        Arrays.sort(input1);

        for(int i = 0; i < input1.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < input2.length; j++) {
                if (input1[i] < input2[j]) {
                    continue;
                } else {
                    int temp = input1[i];
                    input1[i]=input2[j];
                    input2[j]=temp;
                }
            }
        }

        for(int i =0 ; i < input1.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(input1[i]);
        }
        Arrays.sort(input2);
        System.out.println("Array 2");
        for(int i = 0; i < input2.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(input2[i]);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array1= {2,7} ;   
        int[] array2= {5,3,8,1} ;
        mergeArray(array1, array2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Posting the code alone as answer doesn't help. Please elaborate your answer with some description.